# How do I isolate/solve for $\theta$ in $\sin (2\theta) = 4 \cos (2\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Isolate the variable/solve for $\theta$:
>
> $$\sin (2\theta) = 4 \cos (2\theta)$$

Like which $\cos$ double angle formula would I use? Because there are three of them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin { 2\theta =4\cos { 2\theta  }  } \\ \tan { 2\theta =4 } \\ 2\theta =\arctan { 4+k\pi  } ,k\in { Z }\\ \theta =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \arctan { 4+\frac { k\pi  }{ 2 }  } ,k\in { Z }$$

Answer (score 1):

This equality is equivalent to

$$\tan(2\theta)=4\iff\theta=\frac12\arctan(4)+k\frac\pi2,\; k\in\Bbb Z$$